# Ever vs Never, where to put them and which is better to use

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, colloquial-language

I've a symple question with when to use ever and never.
For example in the following two senteces, which it's grammatically better

> we'll teach them that they won't be able to mess with him, ever

and

> we'll teach them that they won't be able to mess with him, never

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Squatitive Negation

Those aren't equivalent, and in fact one is ungrammatical. Words like *ever* and *any* are [***negative polarity items***](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) in English. When the verb is already negative, you need to use an NPI not another negative.

- They will never be able to mess with him. (verb is positive, so needs a regular negative word)
- They won’t ***ever*** be able to mess with him. (verb is negative, so needs an NPI)

Here's the same sort of thing with *any*:

- We have no bananas. (verb is positive, so needs a regular negative word)
- We don’t have ***any*** bananas. (verb is negative, so needs an NPI)

There are lost of other like this. It’s a topic still open for research, one [we still don’t know ***squat***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/349047/2085)* about.

---

<sub>**PS:** Yes, *squat* is actually an NPI; follow the links — twice — for why. :-)</sub>